# A function is called nice

Tags: functions, functional-equations

We define a real-valued function to be nice, if

$\dfrac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} \ge f\bigg(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\bigg) + |x - y|$

holds for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that there doesn't exist any nice functions.

**My Work:**

Let $y=-x$. Then we have,
$\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} \ge f(0) +2x$

Similarly for $x=y=0$ we have,
$f(0) \ge f(0)$

I stopped because I think I am going in a completely wrong direction. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This is such a funny definition, since there are so many real-valued functions that I would consider to be "nice"!

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I didn't get you. I just got asked this question where I have to prove that no such nice functions exist. Can you give any counter-example?

Comment: The condition is a much stronger form of convexity. It might help to draw some pictures. My sense is that any function obeying that would have to grow too quickly to have an extension to the whole real line.

Comment: You should probably call such a function a 'strange' function.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I get it. But any clue how to prove this rigorously?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Indeed, it is strange. Can you help out?

Answer (score 10):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)-2f(0)$. From your observation it follows that $g(x) \geq 2f(0)+4x-2f(0)=4x \geq 0$ for any $x \geq 0$.

Now check that $\frac {g(x)+g(y)} 2 \geq g(\frac {x+y} 2)+|x-y|$ and note that $g(0)=0$ . Put $y=0$ to get $g(x)\geq 2g(\frac x  2) +2|x|$ for any $x \geq 0$. Iteration of this gives $g(x)\geq 2^{n}g(\frac x {2^{n}})+2^{n}|x|$. The first term is non-negative (for $x \geq 0$) so $g(x)\geq 2^{n}|x|$ . You get a  contradiction by letting $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Understood. But I have one doubt. Do we need to explicitly check that $\dfrac{g(x)+g(y)}{2} \ge g(\dfrac{x+y}{2}) + |x-y|$ ? Or do we state something or is it trivial?

Comment: Apply the hypothesis with $x$ changed to $-x$ and $y$ changed to $-y$ and and  add the two inequalities. You can see that the inequality I stated for $g$ is satisfied. @user9888663

Comment: Yes thank you got it. Can you just briefly explain the iteration part? I think I know what's happening. But I wanna be sure. Thank you

Comment: $g(x)\geq 2g(\frac x 2)+2|x|$ Now change $x$ to $\frac x  2$ in this to get $g(\frac x 2 )\geq 2g(\frac x 4)+|x|$. Use this for the first term in $g(x)\geq 2g(\frac x 2)+2|x|$ to get $g(x)\geq 4g(\frac x 4)+4|x|$. And so on. By induction you get $g(x)\geq 2^{n}g(\frac x {2^{n}})+2^{n}|x|$. @user9888663